Converting 3d coplanar points to space of 2d plane then back into 3d
I have the equation of an arbitrary plane of the form $Ax+By+Cz+d= 0$.
I also have a set of points lying on this plane, $\{p_1, p_2, ... , p_i\}$ where each $p_i$ is an $(x,y,z)$ coordinate. I would like to be able to transform each $p_i$ into a $p'_i$ to a 2D coordinate space $(U,V)$ defined on the plane.
I would then like to convert any $p'_i$ defined on this new coordinate space $(U,V)$ back to a 3D $(X,Y,Z)$ coordinate in the original space.
What is the most efficient way to do this, knowing that both forward and reverse transformation of the points is necessary, and that I may want to perform the reverse transformation from 2D back to 3D on any arbitrary point defined in $(U,V)$ space.

Hi, welcome to MSE, I suggested a minor edit to index the letters on each of the $p_i$, which I assume was what you originally meant; if not , please feel free to reject.

Thanks for the edit, it is helpful & I have accepted :)

It would be helpful if you could add some context to your question. Are you familiar with 3D rotation matrices? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix Do you know about the cross product? Can you transform the points on your plane to the parallel plane through the origin?

We can assume WLOG that at least one of two first coefficients $A,B$ are $\ne 0$ (if that wasn't the case, we would have an equation $Cz+d=0$ for which the issue can be treated in a separate, simple manner).
As the equation of a plane can be multiplied by any constant, in particular by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$, we can assume WLOG again that
$$A^2+B^2=1$$
which means that
$$A=\cos a, \ \ B=\sin a$$
for a certain $a$. Therefore the equation of the plane is :
$$x \cos a  + y \sin a + z C' + d'=0\tag{1}$$
but we will drop the primes in the sequel. The normal vector to the plane is
$$N=\pmatrix{\cos a\\ \sin a \\ C}.$$
$$\text{Together with } \ \ \ P=\pmatrix{-\sin a \\ \ \ \ \cos a \\ 0}, \ \ Q=\pmatrix{C \cos a \\ C \sin a \\ -1},\tag{2}$$
$(N,P,Q)$ is an orthogonal basis of the 3D space (check their orthogonality : $N.P = N.Q = P.Q = 0$)
Being given a point $p$ with 3D coordinates $X,Y,Z$, its decomposition on this basis is :
$$\begin{cases}X&=& u \cos a &-& v \sin a &+& w C \cos a \\
Y&=& u \sin a &+& v \cos a &+& w C \sin a \\
Z&=& u C &&  &-& w\\
\end{cases}\tag{3}$$
An important remark takes place here : the value of $u$ is constant because the dot product of $\vec{Op}.N$ is constant !
One can compute this constant which is :
$$u=\frac{-d}{1+C^2}\tag{4}$$
Inverting system (3), that we give under a matricial form, we are able to compute $v,w$ as functions of $x,y,z$ :
$$\pmatrix{u\\v\\w}=\tfrac{-1}{1+C^2}\pmatrix{-\cos a&-\sin a& -C\\ (1+C^2)\sin a&-(1+C^2)\sin a&0\\-C \cos a &-C \cos a &1}\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}\tag{4}$$
$v,w$ are the planar coordinates you are looking for.
Now, the "way back machine" is simple : having $v,w$ how to retrieve $x,y,z$ ? Plainly by using formulas (3) because $u$ is known.
Remark : vectors $N$ and $Q$ can be normalized by dividing them by their (common) norm : $\sqrt{1+C^2}$.

I'm not familiar with the notation $\vec{Op}$. I assume it's the vector from the origin to the point $p$. Or something. ;)

That's it. Do you agree with the rest of my explanations ?

Sure. I would do it slightly differently (and use normalised basis vectors), but your approach is perfectly fine, and probably easier to follow than my method.
